# Create a plot of lx against age in RStudio

Tags: r

I am working with life tables in R Studio and am looking to produce a plot against one variable against another.

```
head(mylifetab)
Year Age      mx      qx   ax     lx  dx    Lx      Tx    ex Age2 age.numeric
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSgPO.png)

I am looking at plotting lx against age.numeric.

The plot that is has created.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgoxW.png)

Comment: Hi @Natlia Antipenkove, could you please provide us a reproducible data (sample) using `dput(mylifetab)`? So then we could help you better.

Comment: Hi @Quinten, yes apologies about that. I have attempted to work this out on my own and have come up with plot(mylifetab$age.numeric, mylifetab$lx, main="Survival Function", xlab = "Age", ylab = "Number of persons alive at Age x"). I can't seem to add the output to dput(mylifetab) as there are too many 'characters'. I have added a photo of what the table looks like to the original q.

Comment: What type of plot are you trying to make?

Answer (score 0):

I took the lx and age.numeric values from your image. The data looks like this:

```
mylifetab <- data.frame(lx = c(100000, 99455, 99404, 99390, 99365, 99351),
                        age.numeric = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

      lx age.numeric
1 100000           0
2  99455           1
3  99404           2
4  99390           3
5  99365           4
6  99351           5
```

If you want to plot the age and lx, you can use this code:

```
plot(mylifetab$age.numeric, 
     mylifetab$lx, 
     main = "Survival Function", 
     xlab = "Age",
     ylab = "Number of persons alive at Age x")
```

Output:

[image]